# How to find duplicate issues in Jira Rest API

Tags: python, python-3.x, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I am using Jira rest API for python3.7. I am able to get the linked issues of Jira, i.e parent and child Jira relations to a particular issue can be identified. But I am not sure that how to find duplicate issues to a particular Jira.
Below is the code I am using to identify parent-child relationships.

```
    for links in issue.fields.issuelinks:
        if hasattr(links, "outwardIssue"):
            outwardIssue = links.outwardIssue
        elif hasattr(links, "inwardIssue"):
            inwardIssue = links.inwardIssue
```

Need help to find duplicate jira issues.
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a link.type attribute that will be an id of one of the Jira link types defined for your instance. The link type "Duplicate" is a standard Jira issue link type. Check for links of that type

Comment: Can you provide an illustration with a code example if possible